# Gaussian Elimination Correctness

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

One of the basic techniques is Gaussian Elimination on a matrix. The way I'm thinking of matrices is the row picture where each row represents a certain linear equation so Gaussian Elimination is really about adding and subtracting linear equations.

Adding and subtracting linear equations works because you are adding or subtracting equal values from each side of the equation.
But in certain examples, I am still confused why is it valid to add linear equations together and how to interpret the resulting equation.
For example, let's take 1) x - y = 3 and 2) x + 2y = 5. Adding them together -> 3) 2x + y = 8.

A) How do I interpret this third equation? Is it true that that the solution to a system of 1) and 2) will always lie on line 3)?

B) If yes, what about these two equations

1. x = 5 and 2) x = 3.

This is obviously has no solution but we could obtain 3) 2x = 8 -> x = 4.
Why is that incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Gaussian elimination does *not* plainly add equations together. In Gaussian elimination, you *preserve* one equation and replace the other with a sum of the two, or with the second plus some factor times the first. So if you have two equations $E_1=0$ and $E_2=0$, you transform them to, again, two equations $E_1=0$ and $E_2+\lambda E_1=0$ for some number $\lambda$. (In special cases, if $\lambda=1$, you've added $E_1$ to $E_2$; if $\lambda=-1$, you've taken away $E_1$ from $E_2$.)

Now, *this converts the system of equations into an **equivalent** system of equations*. If $E_1=0$ and $E_2=0$, *then* $E_1=0$ and $E_2+\lambda E_1=0$. Conversely, if $E_1=0$ and $E_2+\lambda E_1=0$, then (by taking *away* $\lambda E_1$) from the second equation you get back to $E_1=0, E_2=0$.

The fact that the original and transformed system of equations are **equivalent** means that all the solutions of the original system are also solutions of the transformed system, *and vice versa*. You cannot gain a non-solution, you cannot lose a solution. That is why it works.

If you merely add two equations and you continue work with one single equation, e.g. you replace $E_1=0, E_2=0$ with $E_1+E_2=0$, you have transformed the original system into a *non-equivalent* system of equations. The latter is **implied** by the former but it is **not equivalent** to the former. (Sum of two zeros is zero, but if a sum of two numbers is zero, they don't need both to be zero.) Any solution of the original system is still the solution of the new system, but there may be solutions of the new system which are not solutions of the original system.

That is exactly what happened when you added $x=3$ and $x=5$ to obtain a single equation $2x=8$: the solution $x=4$ is only the solution of the new system, and it is not a solution of the original system (which, as you said, has no solutions).